# add an angularjs material element via a directive's link function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to add the material angularjs `md-input-container` to the DOM via a directive's compile function as following :

```
element.after(`
    <md-input-container md-theme-watch="true" flex>
        <label for="sampletext1">Champ texte</label>
        <input name="sampletext1" type="text"
               class="ng-tree-search">
    </md-input-container>
`)
```

But when I open the page, the element looses it's default behaviour and looks like this :

[image]

Instead it should look like this :

[image]

This only works when I add the element in the html, but in my case I want to add it via the link function of the directive that creates that treeview.

Comment: Why on Earth would you want to do that? Don't add elements with AngularJS directives in the DDO compile function. Instead find another way to achieve what you want.

Comment: Any error on console? Because I've tried with simplest example, it seems to be working fine.. There's possibility that treeview directive's compile function (has some error & thus) failing. Can you show the directives code in which you're performing above operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compile the element's template first in link function of directive. This's how you can do that:

```
var elemHtml = `
            <md-input-container md-theme-watch="true" flex>
                <label for="sampletext1">Champ texte</label>
                <input name="sampletext1" type="text"
                       class="ng-tree-search">
            </md-input-container>
        `;
element.after($compile(elemHtml)(scope));
```

Don't forget to pass the $compile in function of the directive.

Working Plunker link: https://plnkr.co/edit/dKjanhRioFWtWcm4Hoki?p=preview

In question you said you've that in compile function but in title you're saying link function. Actually in compile function you don't need to use $compile in above case. (But if it's inside link function it's needed).

Example of having that inside compile function: https://plnkr.co/edit/By9Io583s6ZxffLyrHTt?p=preview

Comment: Sorry my bad I meant link function, btw $compile function has solved the problem, thanks.